git push got stuck all of a sudden and not working
I'm working on my repo - https://github.com/ILoveDotNet/ilovedotnet . All of the sudden git push gets stuck and not working. I tried all the possible solutions listed in stack overflow on similar topic and tried for more than 2 hours but still not able to figure out the issue. Here is the logs.
PS C:\Repos\ilovedotnet> git add .
PS C:\Repos\ilovedotnet> git commit -m "test"
[main 2f5026ae8] test
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
PS C:\Repos\ilovedotnet> git push
Enumerating objects: 7, done.
Counting objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 348 bytes | 174.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (3/3), completed with 3 local objects.

It gets stuck at above logs.. and nothing happens
Steps to reproduce:

Clone - https://github.com/ILoveDotNet/ilovedotnet
make changes
git commit and git push to main

Update 1:
I tried to create a test branch and push but nothing happens.
Here are the logs:
1234@Abdul-ka-MacBook-Pro ilovedotnet % git checkout -b test
Switched to a new branch 'test'
1234@Abdul-ka-MacBook-Pro ilovedotnet % git push                   
fatal: The current branch test has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin test

To have this happen automatically for branches without a tracking
upstream, see 'push.autoSetupRemote' in 'git help config'.

1234@Abdul-ka-MacBook-Pro ilovedotnet % git push --set-upstream origin test
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0 (from 0)

Please assist me on what I'm missing.

I don't have a solution but just now I started having the same problem with pushing to a Github repository. Perhaps they have some problems on their side?

The first issue seems to be server downtime or something like that. If you do not have an error or an effective failure, just a long wait, then it looks like a server downtime or something related to maintenance or so. Try again later and see whether it works and if not what the error will be. As about the second problem, you cannot just push a new branch by default. You could just do
git push -u origin the-branch-name

which sets the upstream branch which is to receive your push.

Thank you for the response. To push a new branch I already tried git push --set-upstream origin test as mentioned in Update 1 last command in logs...but still no luck

it started working now

@fingers10 happy to help. Indeed, it appears to be the case that there was a temporary issue accessing your repo.
